# Add typings for array-like only property values from a generic object

Tags: typescript

Suppose you have a function that:

1. takes an object with multiple properties and a property name;
2. checks if the property contains an array;
3. if so, it does something with it (ie. printing the values it contains)

Here we have an example:

```ts
function printIfKeyIsAnArray(values, field) {
  if (Array.isArray(values[field])) {
    values[field].map(x => console.log(x));
  }

  return null;
}
```

The following types seem to work correctly, and `ArrayValues<T>` only extracts array-like types from the properties of `T`:

```ts
type StringKey<T> = keyof T

type ArrayValues<T> = T[
  {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? K : never
  }[keyof T]
]

type X = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string[],
  qux: number[],
}

// const arrayValues: string[] | number[] -> Hurray!
const arrayValues: ArrayValues<X> = ['a'];
```

Now, if I try to use these types in the function above, Typescript raises an error:

```ts
function printIfKeyIsAnArray<T>(values: T, field: keyof T) {
  if (Array.isArray(values[field])) {
    const arrayValue = values[field] as ArrayValues<T>;
    arrayValue.map(x => console.log(x));
  }

  return null;
}
```

[image]

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'
```

Why? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but what you're doing here is logically `forEach`, not `map`, since you don't want to build a new array; and you can write `.forEach(console.log)` without writing a lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `Array.isArray` doesn't narrow the type of `values[field]` because the latter isn't an expression that can be narrowed. If you assign `values[field]` to a variable first, then it all type-checks with no need to do anything fancy:

```js
function printIfKeyIsAnArray<T>(values: T, field: keyof T) {
  const p = values[field];
  // inferred type p: T[keyof T]
  if (Array.isArray(p)) {
    // narrowed type to p: T[keyof T] & any[]
    p.map(x => console.log(x));
  }

  return null;
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAksA0gUwE8sBnAQTDNVQENCAeAFQD4AKANxoBsR8SAuRIwA0iYDHxcAJoIDWROMCEBKRAG8AUIkQQEJKCkQBeRJx58A2uMlSAugG4tiAPTPEGYPmr4piKIWR8FEFGC3lCRSFbJxglVipaQgA6GHJqOlZkZVVNbW1XRDAaajgAdx8-AKCoOGChMIUlRltEADJEGjBCC2i8lCSAWxpkVgAPY2YdPTgufCSuOABzMezHbQBfDSdUfCgQVCQwEC4uR3WgA)

If you just wanted to know how to fix the `ArrayValues` generic type, move the `T[...]` to apply to `K` instead of the whole thing:

```js
type ArrayValues<T> =
  {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K] : never
  }[keyof T]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what changes when you move `T[...]` to apply to `K` instead of the whole thing? Inspecting the types they seem exactly the same, but your code works and mine not :D Any documentation?

Comment: My best guess is that Typescript is able to infer that `T[K] extends any[] ? T[K] : never` is a subtype of `any[]` because of a straightforward rule about conditional types, whereas the other version is too complicated to have a particular type-inference rule associated with it. Even the simpler `type Test<T, K extends keyof T> = T[T[K] extends any[] ? K : never]` isn't inferred as a subtype of `any[]`.